# How to delete iCloud for Windows but keep calendar and mail synced in Outlook 2016?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

*I currently have this frustrating issue which I'm not sure how to resolve:*

I wanted to delete the iCloud suite for Windows since it uses my system resources but at the same time I want to keep the calendars and email sync I setup in Outlook through the iCloud sofware.

Every time I want to delete iCloud, it removes all the settings and folders in Outlook and puts them in a new account called iCloud Archive, which does not keep in sync with my iCloud account.

I was wondering how can I delete iCloud for Windows but keep my iCloud calendar and mail in sync with Outlook 2016?

*Many thanks.*

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to sync and how.  If you want to keep syncing with your iCloud account then you need to keep the iCloud Control Panel.  As far as I know you cannot access the iCloud service without it.  You can move away from iCloud completely and still do the same but you need access to a WebDAV server or use apps available for use between PCs.  Some web hosting companies provide WebDAV for a small fee.

Another option is that you can use the Yahoo and MSN/Hotmail calendars to share your appointments with other people or devices. Hotmail Live users can use the Outlook Hotmail Connector to sync their appointments and contacts with the web-based calendar and contacts.

You can sync your emails between your PC and iPhone using iTunes without using iCloud.  I used to do this when I had iPhones. You would need to [use a WebDAV server or apps](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/sharing/sharing-outlook-calendar-and-contacts/) to share your calendars between devices.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no way to sync iCloud calendars and contacts without having the iCloud for Windows software installed?